# Add input and select field dynamically using jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

In my below code I am trying to add rows dynamically on click on a button. It has been working smooth for the INPUT fields, but it fails to add row if we include SELECT field in the code.

Also post adding the row the data should get submitted for all tr added.

```
@if (Model != null && Model.Count > 0)
        {


            int j = 0;
            foreach (var i in Model)
            {
        <tr style="border:1px solid black">
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a[j].Project,new { @required="required"})</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a[j].Task, new { @required = "required" })</td><td></td>
            <td>@Html.DropDownList("Status", ViewBag.EnumList as SelectList)</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a[j].UserId, new { @class = "id", @type = "hidden" })</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a[j].Email,new { @class="email",@type="hidden"})</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a[j].Date, new { @type="hidden"})</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                @if (j > 0)
                {
                    //<a href="#" class="remove btn btn-warning" id="delete">Remove</a>
                    <button class="remove btn btn-warning" id="delete">Remove</button>
                }
                </td>
        </tr>
                j++;
            }
```

jQuery as below

```
$("#addNew").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var $tableBody = $("#dataTable");
                var $trLast = $tableBody.find("tr:last");
                var e = $(".email").val();
                var id = $(".id").val();
                var $trNew = $trLast.clone();

                debugger;
                var suffix = $trNew.find(':input:first').attr('name').match(/\d+/);
                $trNew.find("td:last").html('<a href="#" class="remove" id="delete">Remove</a>');
                $.each($trNew.find(':input'), function (i, val) {
                    // Replaced Name
                    var oldN = $(this).attr('name');
                    var newN = oldN.replace('[' + suffix + ']', '[' + (parseInt(suffix) + 1) + ']');
                    $(this).attr('name', newN);
                    //Replaced value
                    var type = $(this).attr('type');
                    if (type.toLowerCase() == "text") {
                        $("#id").attr('value', id);
                        $("#email").attr('value', e);
                    }

                    // If you have another Type then replace with default value
                    $(this).removeClass("input-validation-error");

                });
                $trLast.after($trNew);

                // Re-assign Validation
                var form = $("form")
                    .removeData("validator")
                    .removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");
                $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);
            });

            // 2. Remove

            $(document).on('click', '#delete', function () {

                $(this).parent().parent().remove();

            });
```

Comment: Check the *rendered* HTML.   It won't post the `<select>` for each row as you have `@Html.DropDownList("Status"` while your rows are all `.TextBoxFor(a => a[j].Project` - so  it should probably be `@Html.DropDownListFor(a => a[j].Status,...`

Comment: `if (type.toLowerCase() == "text") {` means your `[j]` adjustment isn't applied to the `select`

Comment: Unless you have a *custom* model binder, the default one in [tag:asp.net-mvc] does not handle gaps in the indices - so if you have 1,2,3 then delete the 2nd, you get 1,3 and it won't bind the way you'd expect it to

Comment: @Html.DropDownListFor(a=> a[j].Status, ViewBag.EnumList as SelectList,new { @class = "form-control" }) no success yet with above suggestion

Answer (score 0):

-> Add input and Select fields dynamically using jquery and please check the new row adding also contains the selct element.

```
@if (Model != null && Model.Count > 0)
{
    int j = 0;
    foreach (var i in Model)
    {
        <tr style="border:1px solid black">
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a[j].Project, new { @required="required" })</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a[j].Task, new { @required = "required" })</td>
            <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(a => a[j].Status, ViewBag.EnumList as SelectList)</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a[j].UserId, new { @class = "id", @type = "hidden" })</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a[j].Email, new { @class = "email", @type = "hidden" })</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a[j].Date, new { @type = "hidden" })</td>
            <td>
                @if (j > 0)
                {
                    <button class="remove btn btn-warning" id="delete">Remove</button>
                }
            </td>
        </tr>
        j++;
    }
}
```

-> Javascript :-

```
$("#addNew").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $tableBody = $("#dataTable");
    var $trLast = $tableBody.find("tr:last");
    var e = $(".email").val();
    var id = $(".id").val();
    var $trNew = $trLast.clone();

    var suffix = $trNew.find(':input:first').attr('name').match(/\d+/);
    $trNew.find("td:last").html('<button class="remove btn btn-warning" id="delete">Remove</button>');

    $.each($trNew.find(':input'), function (i, val) {
        // Replaced Name
        var oldN = $(this).attr('name');
        var newN = oldN.replace('[' + suffix + ']', '[' + (parseInt(suffix) + 1) + ']');
        $(this).attr('name', newN);

        // If you have another Type then replace with default value
        $(this).removeClass("input-validation-error");
    });

    // Re-assign Validation
    var form = $("form")
        .removeData("validator")
        .removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");
    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);

    $trLast.after($trNew);
});
```

-> in this code , the new row includes the select field along with the input field and it will be added dynamically when you click the Add button.